# The difference between the user's old and new password isn't checked in Oracle APEX

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I’m working with an Oracle APEX application and today I have discovered that the password verify function, which is set up for several profiles, doesn’t work properly, because the parameter, which stands for the old password, turned out to be null.

My password verify function `F_VERIFY_PASSWORD` is based on the example from the Oracle admin file `utlpwdmg.sql`: the code changes were made only for the parts which are not related to the comparison of the old password and the new one. The function code is presented below (excluding the parts which make no problems):

```
create or replace function F_VERIFY_PASSWORD
 (
  USERNAME     varchar2
 ,PASSWORD     varchar2
 ,OLD_PASSWORD varchar2
) return boolean is
…
  DIFFER integer; 
  MINDIFFER number := 3;
…
begin
…
  -- Check that the new password differs from the previous one no less than in MINDIFFER positions.
  if OLD_PASSWORD is not null
  then
    DIFFER := LENGTH(OLD_PASSWORD) - LENGTH(PASSWORD);
    DIFFER := ABS(DIFFER);
    if DIFFER < MINDIFFER
    then
      if LENGTH(PASSWORD) < LENGTH(OLD_PASSWORD)
      then
        M := LENGTH(PASSWORD);
      else
        M := LENGTH(OLD_PASSWORD);
      end if;
      for I in 1 .. M
      loop
        if SUBSTR(PASSWORD,I,1) != SUBSTR(OLD_PASSWORD,I,1)
        then
          DIFFER := DIFFER + 1;
        end if;
      end loop;
      if DIFFER < MINDIFFER
      then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20011,'The new password must differ from the old one no less than in 3 positions!');
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
  -- Return TRUE, if all is correct. 
  return(true);
end;
```

The changing password itself is made by the means of the procedure `P_CHANGE_PASS`, which is executed in Oracle APEX application. The code of it is presented below (excluding the parts which make no problems).

```
create or replace procedure P_CHANGE_PASS
 (
  NEWPASS    varchar2
 ,NEWPASS2   varchar2
 ,USR        varchar2
) as
…
begin
…
  --changing the password
  begin
    execute immediate 'alter user ' || USR || ' identified by ' || NEWPASS;
  exception
    when others then
      …
  end;
end;
```

I’ve tried the following steps to make the verify function include the check of differences between the old and new passwords:

1. revoked the privilege `ALTER USER` from the user `APEX_PUBLIC_USER`;
2. added the statement `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` to the code of the
   “client” procedure `P_CHANGE_PASS`;
3. added `REPLACE <old password>`
   to the `ALTER USER` command (it’s awful thing, but I made it just
   for debugging).

None of these actions helped me to solve my problem. So, what should I do to make the parameter `OLD_PASSWORD` not null in the function `F_VERIFY_FUNCTION`?

I use Oracle 11g (version 11.2.0.3.0), Oracle APEX 4.2.6.00.03.

Comment: `replace` may be awful but it's the only way for the function to ever know what the old password was, since it is stored as a one-way hash. If the function still sees null for that then presumably it doesn't think the user is changing their own password; which user is connected and executing your procedure, the actual DB user or an APEX user? (i.e in your procedure, is `USR` the same as `USER`?)

Comment: APEX_PUBLIC_USER executes the procedure, USR is the actual user, which is known in APEX through the global variable.